# how to ignore double white-spaces during text matching using Xpath

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I have a html code like this:

```html
<div class="main">
     <div class ="first">
        <p>just text</p>
                      </div>
     <div class= "second">
        <p>some text</p>
                      </div>
     <div class= "third">
        <p>some  text having double white-space</p>
                      </div>
</div>
```

and  use Xpath like this: `//div/p[contains(text(),'some text')]`
But unfortunately in any place of the "some text" inside element p can be double white-spaces. So I need to ignore them during this matching. I know I can use Xpath expression like this `translate(normalize-space(//div/p), ' ', '')` but it will find all elements p and just replace double white-spaces without matching "some text"!
Is it possible to match "some text" but ignore double white-spaces in the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When selecting a set of nodes using XPath 1.0, the XPath can't *change* the nodes that are returned in the result. You can only select nodes as they already are. You can use the following to ignore the double spaces when doing the selection:

```
//div/p[contains(normalize-space(), 'some text')]
```

This will return the set of `p`s that you are looking for, but their text content will be kept as it originally was. If you then want to obtain the text values without the duplicate spaces, you can iterate through this node set and strip out the spaces from the values one by one. You haven't told us anything about the code you're using to carry out these queries, so it's hard to tell you precisely how you would modify your code to do this. If you can show us your code, I can show you how to get it to do what you need.

Comment: OK then. just I thought it's possible to do that using one Xpath expression. Thanks for your answer @JLRishe